# Обрезается тень bxSlider

Tags: javascript, html, css

Что нужно сделать, чтобы отображалась тень у первого и последнего слайда? [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/m9rhaafc/)

HTML:

```
    <ul class="bxslider">
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item__img"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt=""/></div>
      <div class="item__text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste quo praesentium aperiam blanditiis repellendus dicta, sunt perspiciatis, reiciendis fuga mollitia optio quae! Illum voluptates deleniti assumenda vitae, numquam, architecto amet.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item__img"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt=""/></div>
      <div class="item__text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem impedit facere, repudiandae eos, perspiciatis perferendis! Sit incidunt omnis magni velit, laborum quia vel culpa, cumque debitis reiciendis quis minima praesentium.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item__img"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt=""/></div>
      <div class="item__text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A harum saepe aut provident sed. 
      <div class="item__text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa nam voluptatibus amet dolorum tempora soluta incidunt consectetur dolor, illum est aut accusamus facilis, impedit aliquam laudantium voluptas dolore saepe beatae.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.item {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        auto: true,
        pager: false,
        minSlides: 3,
        maxSlides: 3,
        slideWidth: 270,
        slideMargin: 30
    });
});
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте, если используете этот слайдер, вот решение - http://jsfiddle.net/m9rhaafc/2/ 
если же другой, используйте псевдо-класс **first-chidl** и **last-child**

javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    pager: false,
    minSlides: 3,
    maxSlides: 3,
    slideWidth: 270,
    slideMargin: 30
});
  var shd = $(".bxslider li:not(.bx-clone)");
$(shd).children(".item").first().addClass("shadow");
$(shd).children(".item").last().addClass("shadow");
});
```

css:

```css
.item {
background-color: #fff;

}

.shadow{
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

item*

Answer (score 1):

тень обрезается из-за того что

```
.bx-viewport{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; <!-- это свойство обрезает тень -->
    position: relative;
    height: 277px;
}
```

удалите - `slideMargin: 30`

добавьте `.item - margin: 0 15px;`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    pager: false,
    minSlides: 3,
    maxSlides: 3,
    slideWidth: 270,
    //slideMargin: 30
  });
});
```

```css
/**
 * bxSlider v4.2.5
 * Copyright 2013-2015 Steven Wanderski
 * Written while drinking Belgian ales and listening to jazz

 * Licensed under MIT (http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)
 */

/** VARIABLES 
===================================*/

/** RESET AND LAYOUT
===================================*/

.bx-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 60px;
  padding: 0;
  *zoom: 1;
  -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
  touch-action: pan-y;
}
.bx-wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.bxslider {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.bxslider {
  list-style: none;
}
.bx-viewport {
  /*fix other elements on the page moving (on Chrome)*/
  -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
}
/** THEME
===================================*/

.bx-wrapper {
  /*  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  background: #fff;*/
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  width: 100%;
}
/* LOADER */

.bx-wrapper .bx-loading {
  min-height: 50px;
  background: url('images/bx_loader.gif') center center no-repeat #ffffff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2000;
}
/* PAGER */

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: .85em;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #666;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a {
  background: #666;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  outline: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.active,
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:focus {
  background: #000;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager-item,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-controls-auto-item {
  display: inline-block;
  *zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager-item {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
/* DIRECTION CONTROLS (NEXT / PREV) */

.bx-wrapper .bx-prev {
  left: 10px;
  background: url('images/controls.png') no-repeat 0 -32px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-prev:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-prev:focus {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-next {
  right: 10px;
  background: url('images/controls.png') no-repeat -43px -32px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-next:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-next:focus {
  background-position: -43px 0;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -16px;
  outline: 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a.disabled {
  display: none;
}
/* AUTO CONTROLS (START / STOP) */

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
  text-align: center;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start {
  display: block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 11px;
  outline: 0;
  background: url('images/controls.png') -86px -11px no-repeat;
  margin: 0 3px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start.active,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start:focus {
  background-position: -86px 0;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop {
  display: block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 9px;
  height: 11px;
  outline: 0;
  background: url('images/controls.png') -86px -44px no-repeat;
  margin: 0 3px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop.active,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop:focus {
  background-position: -86px -33px;
}
/* PAGER WITH AUTO-CONTROLS HYBRID LAYOUT */

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-pager {
  text-align: left;
  width: 80%;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-controls-auto {
  right: 0;
  width: 35px;
}
/* IMAGE CAPTIONS */

.bx-wrapper .bx-caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #666;
  background: rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.75);
  width: 100%;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-caption span {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial;
  display: block;
  font-size: .85em;
  padding: 10px;
}
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.item {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 15px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item__img">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="item__text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A harum saepe aut provident sed. Aliquam beatae omnis perferendis, ex numquam! Debitis culpa praesentium, sunt modi iusto, quaerat repellendus voluptatibus distinctio.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item__img">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="item__text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa nam voluptatibus amet dolorum tempora soluta incidunt consectetur dolor, illum est aut accusamus facilis, impedit aliquam laudantium voluptas dolore saepe beatae.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item__img">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="item__text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste quo praesentium aperiam blanditiis repellendus dicta, sunt perspiciatis, reiciendis fuga mollitia optio quae! Illum voluptates deleniti assumenda vitae, numquam, architecto amet.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item__img">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="item__text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem impedit facere, repudiandae eos, perspiciatis perferendis! Sit incidunt omnis magni velit, laborum quia vel culpa, cumque debitis reiciendis quis minima praesentium.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item__img">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="item__text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A harum saepe aut provident sed. Aliquam beatae omnis perferendis, ex numquam! Debitis culpa praesentium, sunt modi iusto, quaerat repellendus voluptatibus distinctio.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item__img">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="item__text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa nam voluptatibus amet dolorum tempora soluta incidunt consectetur dolor, illum est aut accusamus facilis, impedit aliquam laudantium voluptas dolore saepe beatae.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item__img">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="item__text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste quo praesentium aperiam blanditiis repellendus dicta, sunt perspiciatis, reiciendis fuga mollitia optio quae! Illum voluptates deleniti assumenda vitae, numquam, architecto amet.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item__img">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="item__text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem impedit facere, repudiandae eos, perspiciatis perferendis! Sit incidunt omnis magni velit, laborum quia vel culpa, cumque debitis reiciendis quis minima praesentium.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```